# Call function when collections are modified

Tags: python, collections

I am writing an addon and I would like to update some of the properties whenever collections change: a new collection is created, a collection is removed, a collection is renamed.

I am trying to use msgbus, but I haven't figured out what key actually gets triggered with these actions. My latest attempt was to follow the "Outliner > Data API" tree to find where the collections were:

```
subscribe_to = bpy.types.BlendData,"collections"
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=owner,
    args=(),
    notify=updateList
)
```

I have a `print` in `updateList` to help me see in the system console when it gets triggered, but none of my attempts so far has been successful when renaming or adding collections. What key should I use for this? Or, is there a better approach?

Once this one works I would do a similar thing with the objects in a collection, so a way to figure out how to find the correct key for msgbus (if that's the right way) would be helpful.

I am currently using Blender 2.91, but I won't mind updating it if I need to. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hello, do you want a different callback when a collection is renamed, moved, deleted, added or do you want to only be notified if there is change, whatever it may be to the collection system ?

Comment: I will be calling the same function regardless of the event, but I am OK with registering different msgbus/operators/whatever if that's necessary